# the trait `for<'r> core::ops::FnMut<(&'r &(K, T),)>` is not implemented for the type `P`

Tags: rust

I want a sorted vector of (Key, Type), which is sorted only by Key.

I came up with the code below:

```
struct SortedVec<K, T> {
    data: Vec<(K, T)>
}

impl<K: Ord, T> SortedVec<K, T> {
    fn new() -> SortedVec<K, T> {
        SortedVec { data: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn add(&mut self, k: K, t: T) {
        self.data.push((k, t));
        self.data.sort_by(|a, b| a.0.cmp(&b.0));
    }

    fn find<P>(&self, predicate: P) -> Option<&(K, T)> where P: FnMut(&(K, T)) -> bool {
        self.data.iter().find(predicate)
    }
}
```

But this doesn't compile with the following errors:

```
anon>:16:30: 16:45 error: the trait `for<'r> core::ops::FnMut<(&'r &(K, T),)>` is not implemented for the type `P` [E0277]
anon>:16             self.data.iter().find(predicate)
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:16:30: 16:45 error: the trait `for<'r> core::ops::FnOnce<(&'r &(K, T),)>` is not implemented for the type `P` [E0277]
<anon>:16             self.data.iter().find(predicate)
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

I can't find anything wrong with the type 'P'.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's compare the bound on `P` and that required the compiler:

```
// P
        FnMut(    &(K, T)) -> bool

// required
for<'r> FnMut(&'r &(K, T)) -> bool
```

If you change the `where` clause to match the signature asked for by the compiler, it works ([see here](http://is.gd/rEaIse)).

I believe the extra reference (and lifetime) are introduced by the use of `iter`, and thus linked to the lifetime of the iterator, but don't take my word for it.

I would point out, though, that `Vec` has a [`binary_search_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.binary_search_by) which is bound to be more efficient than a linear `find`:

```
fn binary_search_by<F>(&self, f: F) -> Result<usize, usize>
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> Ordering
```

You may wish to use that instead, since you went to the trouble of sorting it.

Comment: I saw for<'r> for the first time. How do we call this syntax? Could you point me out the websites or refereces which describe this syntax. Thanks.

Comment: @xps_l502 Those are known as [higher-ranked trait bounds](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0387-higher-ranked-trait-bounds.md)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the compiler already gave you a hint at the fix! You need to change the "where" clause from

```
fn find<P>(&self, predicate: P) -> Option<&(K, T)> 
    where P: FnMut(&(K, T)) -> bool
```

to

```
fn find<P>(&self, predicate: P) -> Option<&(K, T)> 
   where for<'r> P: FnMut(&'r &(K, T)) -> bool
```